# Google BigQuery - Updating a nested repeated field

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to update the hits.page.pagePath field in the Google Analytics export in BigQuery, however i'm unable to unnest the field using the method outlined in the documentation. In my case, the pagePath field is nested at two levels, "hits" and "page".

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_repeated_records

The following code is incomplete, but I'm stuck with unnesting pagePath from the page RECORD.

```
UPDATE `project-name.datasetId.ga_sessions_yyyymmdd`

SET hits = ARRAY( 
  SELECT page.pagePath FROM UNNEST(hits) as pagePath
  )

WHERE fullVisitorID like "%1%"
```

Has anyone managed to use update this field or a similar one in the GA export?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't quite comprehend what you are trying to do here. Why you want to update the `hits` of `ga_session` tables? Something wrong happened in the export? You want to update it with the same hits the `fullvisitor` had in his session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help get you started. You need to include everything else from `hits` in order to perform the update, including the nested `page`.

```
UPDATE `you_dataset.tablename`
SET hits = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE (
    (SELECT AS STRUCT page.* REPLACE ('foo' AS pagePath)) AS page
  )
  FROM UNNEST(hits) as pagePath
)
WHERE fullVisitorID like "%1%"
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
UPDATE `project-name.datasetId.ga_sessions_yyyymmdd`
SET hits =  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(
      (SELECT AS STRUCT * 
        REPLACE('Your New pagePath' AS pagePath) 
        FROM UNNEST([page])
      ) AS page) 
    FROM UNNEST(hits)
  ) 
WHERE fullVisitorID like "%1%"
```

As you can see in above example you would replace pagePath with string 'Your New pagePath'
Of course in reality you would want to have some logic here - so replace that part to whatever logic you need - like for example you would need to UPPER whole string - you would use something like below

```
        REPLACE(UPPER(pagePath) AS pagePath)
```

Comment: I realized that I screwed up my original answer when someone was asking about it :) Thanks for posting an answer as well!

Comment: sure, I noticed that something not kosher with your original answer so I posted mine :o)

Comment: I had to modify the inner bits to be e.g. `ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(....) FROM UNNEST(page)) as page`, as otherwise i got the "creating nested arrays is unsupported error.