# Google BigQuery - Updating nested Revenue fields

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I tried to apply the solution in [Google BigQuery - Updating a nested repeated field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44907954/google-bigquery-updating-a-nested-repeated-field) to the field hits.transaction.transactionRevenue, but I receive error message:

> Scalar subquery produced more than one element

I have tried to run the following query:

```
UPDATE `project_id.dataset_id.table`
SET hits = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE (
    (SELECT AS STRUCT transaction.* REPLACE (1 AS transactionRevenue)) AS transaction
  )
  FROM UNNEST(hits) as transactionRevenue
)
WHERE (select h.transaction.transactionId from unnest(hits) as h) LIKE 'ABC123XYZ'
```

Are there any obvious mistakes on my part? Would be great if anyone could share some tips or experiences that could help me with this.

What I basically want to do is to set the revenue of a specific transaction to 1.

Many thanks in advance,

David

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
WHERE (select h.transaction.transactionId from unnest(hits) as h) LIKE 'ABC123XYZ'
```

If there is more than one hit in the array, this will cause the error that you are seeing. You probably want this instead:

```
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from unnest(hits) as h WHERE h.transaction.transactionId LIKE 'ABC123XYZ')
```

But note that your UPDATE will now replace *all* elements of the array for any row where this condition is true. What you may want is to move the condition inside the ARRAY function call instead:

```
UPDATE `project_id.dataset_id.table`
SET hits = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE (
    (SELECT AS STRUCT transaction.* REPLACE (1 AS transactionRevenue)) AS transaction
  )
  FROM UNNEST(hits) as h
  WHERE h.transaction.transactionId LIKE 'ABC123XYZ'
)
WHERE true
```

Now the replacement will only apply to hits with a transaction ID matching the pattern.

Comment: Hi Elliott, thank you very much. Also for the tip about moving the WHERE clause into the ARRAY function call. However, if I would like to UPDATE multiple transaction fields, e.g. transactionTax & transactionShipping, in one go, would I need to make "copies" of the ARRAY function call? Or would there be a more elegant solution?

Comment: Another question: The UPDATE function will not work without a WHERE clause after the SET block. Would I just need to add a generic WHERE condition at the end of your suggested solution, e.g. `WHERE true`?

Comment: I updated the answer to add the WHERE true. You can replace multiple fields inside `transaction` by adding more expressions to the REPLACE list.

Comment: Hi again, I just did a test run with `WHERE true` at the end. However, according to BQ, all rows of the table were modified which is a bit troubling as I only want to edit one row or more specifically one record.
If I use the clause `WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from unnest(hits) as h WHERE h.transaction.transactionId LIKE 'ABC123XYZ')` instead of `WHERE true`, then the desired effect seems to take place, i.e. that only one row was updated.

Comment: The reason that using `WHERE true` is okay is that even though you're overwriting all rows, the contents of the arrays that don't match the condition will be the same as before. But yes, you can also use the `WHERE EXISTS ...` clause if you want.